# SVG as graphics template?

Tags: graphics, svg

I need to create graphics for documentation, e.g. different functions of soft-keys or pin assignments for embedded systems with different firmware. My first thought was to use an SVG template, i.e. comfortably create the basic graphic with e.g. Inkscape and then use some XML library to set/replace respective strings for labels automatically. The SVG then can be embedded or rendered to any other format required.
I would like to know other ideas, or if there is some sort of standard method of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

SVG is just XML, hence is fairly easy to generate.

You can easily generate SVG using XSLT: http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/samples/xslt/

Many programming languages provide efficient APIs for manipulating XML, which can also be applied to generate SVG. For example, I have had good success using Python and the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library.